# Save html-page to MySQL DB after being modified with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I want to save an entire HTML-page after it's being modified with Javascript. It's a week schedule, written by my predecessor, that has to be saved per user in a MySQL Database. I've been searching on this topic for hours but haven't found anything useful.

Does anyone have a clue if this is possible? And if so, how this can be done easily?

Comment: Do you want save fields on HTML-Page or do you want to dump the full rendered HTML file?

Comment: well, so first the standard (empty) schedule loads and then you add activities, which changes images in the html with Javascript. So the modified html-file should be stored in the database.

Comment: You should only put the file location in the database, and save the html file on the filesystem somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Obtain the source from the DOM with javascript:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML
```

Then send an Ajax request to your PHP script that stores the value into the database:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("html", document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML);

var oXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
oXHR.open("POST", "http://foo.com/saveHTML.php");
oXHR.send(formData);
```

In your PHP script:

```
$html = $_POST['html'];
... # store it
```

Comment: FormData is only supported from IE10. Any other options to get this thing working?

Answer (score 0):

You can get actual page HTML with Javascript:

```
var html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML
```

And then make a POST request to serverside script which will save that page to database.